# Why is this not a triangulation of the torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex, triangulation, simplicial-complex

I refer to example 4, fig.3.6, p.17 of *Munkres' Algebraic Topology*. He says the given triangulation scheme "does more than paste opposite edges together".

Not clear to me. For those who don't have the book to hand, a rectangle is divided into 6 equal squares by a horizontal midline and two verticals; each square has a south-west to north-east diagonal.

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could add the picture?

Comment: I believe the issue is that if a simplex has vertices $\{v_0, ..., v_n\}$, then that collection of vertices should uniquely identify that $n$-simplex.  In the case of the surface, subdivided as you have described, this fails.  For example, if you take a vertex on the "midline" and the vertex directly above it (which is the same as the one below it by gluing), those two vertices should belong to a unique segment.  *But, they don't.*

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Got to figure out how to do it. But it's really a standard sort of triangulation diagram.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks, I'll see if this sort of argument works on other non-triangulations.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686142/a-diagram-which-is-not-the-torus

Answer (score 8):

Better late than never. The definition of a **simplicial complex** reads as follows.

> A finite (Euclidean) simplicial complex is a finite collection $K$ of
>   simplices in some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, satisfying the
>   following two conditions:
>
> - If $\sigma \in K$, then every face of $\sigma$ is in $K$.
> - The intersection of any two simplices in $K$ is either empty or a face of each.

Now in this case the second point is violated. Consider the triangles $bef$ and $ebc$, then their intersection is $\{e,b\}$ which is not a face of each.

Comment: Edit: nevermind!

Answer (score 1):

Paste the top and bottom edges first to get a cylinder.
Look at the circle on one end. One half of the circle is identified with the other half as each is da. So collapse that circle down to a line. Now do the same at the other end.
Looks like a toothpaste tube with two bottoms and no top.
Now identify the two ad ends. You get a torus with one circle circle on it collapsed to a segment. Looks like this: https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/klein/toredeklein.shtml